# Working with exoPlayer in android, lot of questions

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am switching from mediaplayer to exoplayer in my project and because there is few documentation I wanted to ask some questions here.

I successfully created the player:

```
   exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(1);
   playerControl = new PlayerControl(exoPlayer);
```

and the music starts playing when I click on my music list:

```
    musicList.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {

                    mediaController.show(0);

                    currentPosition = position;
                    URL = musicUrl.get(position);

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL);

                    sampleSource = new DefaultSampleSource(new FrameworkSampleExtractor(getApplicationContext(), uri, null), 2);
                    audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, null, true);

                    exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
                    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);

                }
            })
    );
```

The problem is I don't know how to change the music if I click on another track on the list, if the track number 2 is playing if I click on track numer 6 to change to it.If anyone can guide me with this problem it will be perfect.

I really readed all topics from stackoverflow and I can't find the solution in theyr demo app because there is playing only 1 track, they don't change it.

Comment: I haven't tried to play music, but I supposed you have to reset or clean the player to achieve what you wan't

Comment: The only method I found is release, I tryed something but didn't work.

Comment: if no one can help you, you can try to post on the github of the project, the developers will answer you! https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer#

Comment: Please help me get getDuration() for ExoPlayer and have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777975/not-able-to-get-getduration-for-aac-file-using-exoplayer

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you implement ExoPlayer as in the Demo from google there is ths info about the method stop():

> Calling this method does not reset the playback position. If this
>   player instance will be used.    * to play another video/audio from
>   its start, then {@code seekTo(0)} should be called after stopping the
>   player and before preparing it for the next video.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

at the top of your onItemClick method you should do a check and pause/stop the player.

```
if (exoPlayer != null) {
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    exoPlayer.stop();
    exoPlayer.seekTo(0);
}
mediaController.show(0);
...
YOUR LOGIC + CHANGE SAMPLE & RENDERERS
...
exoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to read about this post. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/463

I was confused about the same situation as you. After reading the post, I found that I was using the same extractor every time. So the first track was able to be played and when it came to the second one, the player ramained in the state of ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING.

so, for you, i recommend you to look at your DefaultSampleSource to find if you made a similar mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer help u. Im using exoplayer on my app and doing something like this. I not initialize ExoPlayer but this is hard to configure. I just create View

```
 <com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.EMVideoView
    android:id="@+id/video_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And in fragment i initialize it

```
@Bind(R.id.video_player)
EMVideoView emVideoView;
```

With butterknife

and for opening music, videos i create CustomAdapter with recyclerView, where i configuring everything for playing content.

so my aplication look like

```
PlayerActivity>
CustomPlayerFragment>
VideoGridAdapter>
```