# Not able to get getDuration() for AAC file using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, exoplayer, android-music-player

I have been trying to stream a `URL` using `ExoPlayer`. The URLs:

STREAM_URL_1 = "http://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/play.mp3"

STREAM_URL_2 = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ok.talk.channels/zakirkhan/Zakir+khan+-+when+my+father+took+my+gf%27s+call.aac"

Both URLs play but I am not able to get the `getDuration()` for STREAM_URL_2 which is an .aac file. The .mp3 works.

The following is how I do it. How do I get the `getDuration()` for the 2nd URL. Even `seekTo()` doesn't work if `getDuration()` doesn't work.

What change should I make? Do I need to change any `Extractor`?

```
player = ExoPlayer.Factory.newInstance(RENDERER_COUNT, MIN_BUFFER_MS, MIN_RE_BUFFER_MS);
playerControl = new PlayerControl(player);
Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

private static final String STREAM_URL = "http://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/play.mp3";
uri = Uri.parse(STREAM_URL);

// Build the video and audio renderers.
DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter(player.getMainHandler(),
    null);
String userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "MyMediaPlayer");
DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter, userAgent, true);
ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(uri, dataSource, allocator,
    BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource,
    null, true);

// Invoke the callback.
TrackRenderer[] renderers = new TrackRenderer[1];
renderers[RadioPlayer.TYPE_AUDIO] = audioRenderer;
player.prepare(renderers);
player.seekTo(0);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong in your code. MP3 files are formatted in such a way that it's possible to calculate the duration of the file, and seek into any position within it.

However, AAC files do not have that luxury. You can't calulate the duration and can't seek within it.

There is a AAC file in Exoplayer Demo APK. I think if you play that, it will exhibit the same behavour.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The same is the issue with that AAC file too. But, when I was using `MediaPlayer` it was possible to get both duration and seek to a location. How can that be replicated?